# $(this) not working x-editable

Tags: jquery, this, edit-in-place

I'm trying to set up a dynamic retrieve of a pk and this selector is not working, here is my code:

```
#html file
<div id="{{task.id}}">
                <h3>
                    <a href="#" id="task">{{ task.task }}</a>
                </h3>
...
</div>

#js file
$("#task").editable({
    type: 'text',
    **pk:  $(this).closest('div').attr('id'),**
    url: '/update_task/' + pk + '/',
    title: 'Enter task',

});
```

this one is not working, but if I write:

```
pk:  $("#task").closest('div').attr('id')
```

will work, but is not convenient for me.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It depends on from which function you are calling `$("#task").editable({ ...})` and how you are invoking *that* function.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: For ex: if you are calling `$("#task").editable({ ...})` from inside the jQuery click handler of an element, `this` will be that element. If you are doing it from `$(document).ready()`, `this` will point to the document object and so on..

Comment: the editable function is inside of `$(document).ready()` and how should I call `this` from inside the `editable` function to target the element I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the options object, and not the jQuery object. If you have the one-off field from which you want to extract the primary key to send to the server, then I would simply do:

```
var $task = $("#task");
$task.editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk:  $task.attr("id"),
    url: '/update_task/' + pk + '/',
    title: 'Enter task',
});
```

If you are using a more generic selector, such as `.someDiv` and want the `pk` for each individual one, you can use the `params` option with a callback, which allows you to append/overwrite the data to be sent, depending on whether you pass an object or a function (function overwrites, see the [docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)):

```
$(".someDiv").editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk:  0,

    // hooray, params takes a callback so
    // we can get the right context
    params: function (params) {
        var data = {};
        data.pk = $(this).closest("div").attr("id"),
        data.makesure = "You know that this will overwrite the original params object";
        data.soPut = "Everything you need into it before returning";
        return data;
    },
    url: '/update_task/' + pk + '/',
    title: 'Enter task'
});
```

p.s. `pk` seems to accept a function too, so I guess you can do this, but I'm in no position to test right now:

```
$("#task").editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk:  function () {
        return $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
    },
    url: '/update_task/' + pk + '/',
    title: 'Enter task'
});
```